# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController inside a view?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller, addressbook

In my tab bar iPad application, one of my tabs needs to have an `"ABPeoplePicker"`, ie a view exactly similar the view that `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` presents. However, only the controller is exposed in the API and Apple warns against having several controllers to manage a single screen.

To expose the idea slightly differently, Apple explains how to use `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` modally. That's about the only use case for the small iPhone screen, but the iPad larger screen allows for a modeless use case inside the screen.

Is this possible or do I have to redesign my picker from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do just that and did not succeed.
A delegate can not be subviewed it seems.